# Calling Apache-Tika from C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, apache-tika

I need to get metadata and content of different files.

In order to do this I have written C++ porgram that sends the file path to Java (using JNI) and Java Class calls Tika gets necessary results and retruns the result to C++. 
My problem is that for files like 10 MB this process takes 130 sn. Which is too much.

I wonder if Tikaserver is already initialized and running. Does JNI allow me to communicate with this Tika process.

if So how to send file name and get result from Tika in C++ ? How can I get the pointer to **jvm** and **JNIEnv**

Here are my current codes of C++ and Java

```
// ConsoleApplication8.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include <windows.h> 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>       
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
clock_t begin = clock();
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[4];

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";           /* disable JIT */
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:/Users/yv/workspace/TServer/bin;C:/Users/yv/workspace/TServer/src/tikaserver12.jar";    // my class and jar is under this directory. /* user classes   */
//  options[2].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_17\\lib";  /* set native library path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\lib */ 
options[2].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_38\\lib";  /* set native library path */
options[3].optionString = "-verbose:jni";

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; 
vm_args.nOptions = 4;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface  pointer in env */
  JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);      

jclass cls = env->FindClass("TikaWrapper");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "pFile","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

const char* utf_string = "Not copied anything yet";
jboolean isCopy;
jstring estr = env->NewStringUTF(" Getten bu string sonuç olarak dönecek");

jstring estr3 = env->NewStringUTF("C:/cu.docx");
estr=(jstring) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, mid, estr3);
utf_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(estr, &isCopy);
cout<<utf_string;


clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout<<elapsed_secs;
if (isCopy == JNI_TRUE) {
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(estr, utf_string);
}

delete[] options;
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

And Java code is as follows

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;


import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultDetector;
import org.apache.tika.detect.Detector;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TikaWrapper {
  static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public  static String pFile(String filename) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("Java ParseFile a geldim elimde : ");
    System.out.println(filename);
    String result=new String();

    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    Detector detector = new DefaultDetector();
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(detector); 
    context.set(Parser.class, parser);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Z:/out.txt");

    URL url;
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.isFile()) {
        url = file.toURI().toURL();
    } else {
        url = new URL(filename);
    }

    InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(url, metadata);
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(outputstream);
    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context);
    metadata.add("metaerdem", "deneme");
    input.close();

    result += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n";
    result += "<document>\n";
    result += "<Name>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY) +"</Name>\n";
    result += "<Title>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.TITLE) +"</Title>\n";
    result += "<Author>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.AUTHOR) +"</Author>\n";
    result += "<LastSavedBy>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.LAST_AUTHOR) +"</LastSavedBy>\n";
    result += "<ContentCreated>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.CREATION_DATE) +"</ContentCreated>\n";
    result += "<DateLastSaved>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.LAST_SAVED) +"</DateLastSaved>\n";
    result += "<TotalEditingTime>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.TOTAL_TIME) +"</TotalEditingTime>\n";
    result += "<Company>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.COMPANY) +"</Company>\n";
    result += "<CharacterCount>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.CHARACTER_COUNT) +"</CharacterCount>\n";
    result += "<WordCount>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.WORD_COUNT) +"</WordCount>\n";
    result += "<ParagraphCount>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.PARAGRAPH_COUNT) +"</ParagraphCount>\n";
    result += "<Pages>"+ metadata.get(Metadata.PAGE_COUNT) +"</Pages>\n";
    result += "<ERDEM>"+ metadata.get("metaerdem") +"</ERDEM>\n";
    result += "<Tags>\n";
    result += "<Content>"+ outputstream.toString() +"</Content>\n";         

    out.println(outputstream.toString());
    return result;
  }         

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String filename= new String();
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("(None)");
        filename="C:\\a.pdf";
        System.out.print("Got the file from Java: " + filename);
        System.out.print(pFile(filename));                  
//          String a=pFile(filename);                   
    } else {
        System.out.println(args.length + " arguments sent to this program");
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i] + " ");
        }
        filename=args[0].toString();
        String son=pFile(filename);
        System.out.print("File is sent from C++ : " + filename);
        System.out.print("Sonuç C++ da yazılacak");
    }
    System.out.print("bitti");          
}

}
```

Comment: Would you not be better off running the [Tika JAXRS Server](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS), then sending the files over the restful interface to it from your c++ code?

Comment: That is what we were doing but we thought instead of a socket level communication it can be faster if we could apply inter-process communication

Comment: Did you benchmark it? Only for files of any noticeable size, the rate limiting step won't be the TCP overhead but instead the work that Tika has to do processing the file